# Vue unit test - ReferenceError: AWS is not defined in App.vue

Tags: amazon-web-services, unit-testing, vue.js, vue-test-utils, aws-sdk-js

I've used aws-sdk npm package in my vuejs app - app.vue file

```
//App.vue
created() {
const value = AWS.config.credentials;
}
```

and while write test for this file like below

```
//App.spec.js
import { mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk-mock';
import App from 'src/App.vue';

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(AWS);
describe('App.vue', () => {
 it('renders app content', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(App, {
    localVue,
  });
  expect(wrapper.isVueInstance()).toBeTruthy();
 });
}
```

and ran the test and got the error

```
App.vue › renders app content
ReferenceError: AWS is not defined
```

Kindly let me know if you have any idea or any issues same like this.

**EDIT:**

AWS is defined globally in main.js

```
//main.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
Vue.use(AWS);
new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

Comment: Where is `AWS` defined in `App.vue`?

Comment: it is defined in main.js globally